# Pipe stops unexpectedly

Tags: macos, bash

I'm running a script that does fine by itself, but stops when piped through less (or other program that grabs the tty).  I've boiled it down to this snippet:

```shell
$ env -i TERM=vt100 bash --norc --noprofile

bash-3.2$ echo `uname;date` | less -EX

[2]+  Stopped                 echo `uname;date` | less -EX
bash-3.2$ fg
echo `uname;date` | less -EX
Darwin Mon Dec 12 13:44:02 PST 2022
```

The same command runs without problems on Linux.   It also runs fine if I put it until a subshell:

```shell
bash-3.2$ (echo `uname;date;`) | less -EX
Darwin Mon Dec 12 13:46:34 PST 2022
```

I can use the subshell as a workaround in my real program, but it's weird.  Any suggestions what is going on?

System info:

```
bash-3.2$ uname -rms
Darwin 21.6.0 x86_64
```

EDIT:
I used backticks above, but using new-style dollar-parens substitutions (which you should always do, I was just writing quickly and) makes no difference here.

```shell
bash-3.2$ echo $(uname -rms;date;) | less -EX

[1]+  Stopped                 echo $(uname -rms;date;) | less -EX
bash-3.2$ fg
echo $(uname -rms;date;) | less -EX
Darwin 21.6.0 x86_64 Mon Dec 12 14:43:47 PST 2022
bash-3.2$
```

EDIT:
Was pointed to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/588228/20881) pointing out that it's not just reading and writing the tty that can generate a SIGTTOU, it's also running ioctls on it (maybe something as seemingly benign as `isatty()` in stdio to determine the default buffering mode?), and this is ultimately a race condition, with the extra processes/substitutions adding enough time to hit or miss the race.

With that in mind, I tried an alternative reproduction:

```
$ for x in $(seq 100); do echo $(true && uname) | less -EX ; done
```

This generates usually between 1-3 stopped jobs on my macbook, might be dependent on how loaded it is.

Adding subshells on the commands seems to make it more reliable, at the expense of making it slower, but the race condition could still be waiting around the corner.

Comment: Strange bug with bash v3? Works fine with bash v5 (installed with homebrew).
Also works fine with `| cat` instead of `| less -EX`! 
Also works: `{ echo $(uname; date); } | less -EX`